# Aggregating an array of swift types

Tags: swift

In Swift, I know that types are classes unto themselves, but I am having a hard time making this work.

I am trying to create a "factory," where I have an `Array` of types, each of which conform to a protocol (so it would actually be an `Array` of protocol), which specifies a static "factory" function.

This would allow me to associate a set of classes with an instance, so that the instance can cycle through the "factory," and instantiate the classes that are associated with that instance.

Here's what I mean:

```
protocol A {
    static func makeAStat() -> A
    func makeADyn() -> A
}

struct APrime: A {
    static func makeAStat() -> A {
        return Self()
    }

    func makeADyn() -> A {
        return Self.makeAStat()
    }
}

let instanceOne = APrime.makeAStat()
let instanceTwo = APrime().makeADyn()

let arrayOf1 = [APrime()]
let instance3 = arrayOf1[0].makeADyn()

//let arrayOf2: [A.Type] = [APrime]
//let instance4 = arrayOf2[0].makeAStat()
```

Note the two commented-out lines. They will break the playground, but I'd like to get something like that working, so I can just say something like "This is a WidgetPlus object, so it gets to pick from these three types as handlers."

Does anyone have a suggestion as to the best way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `.self`

```
let arrayOf2: [A.Type] = [APrime.self]
let instance4 = arrayOf2[0].makeAStat()
```

And for more clarity I'd recommend to write

```
protocol A {
    static func makeAStat() -> Self
    func makeADyn() -> Self
}

struct APrime: A {
    static func makeAStat() -> APrime {
        return APrime()
    }

    func makeADyn() -> APrime {
        return APrime.makeAStat()
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Is it more clear? You can shorten the first to just `.init()` and the second to just `.makeAStat()`. Just gotta move your eyes back up to the return type if it isn't in your working memory. But if you put it all one one line, I don't think it's a problem: `static func makeAStat() -> APrime { .init() }` `func makeADyn() -> APrime { .makeAStat() }`

Comment: Thanks!
I can probably do it with an init(), but I'm sticking with the factory for now. I may do what you say in a refactoring round, once I have everything working properly.